# Write bytearray to file?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have the following:

```
import pyodbc

# ODBC connection to database
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=CCSQLRESUME;DATABASE=ResumeStore;UID=ray;PWD=Yar!')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# SELECT resume data
cursor.execute(
"""SELECT
       rbs.candidate_id,
       rbs.[fileName],
       rbs.resumeData,
       rbs.docType
   FROM [ResumeStore].[dbo].[ResumeBinaryStorage] as rbs (NOLOCK)
   WHERE rbs.candidate_id = 5078707"""
)
```

Upon querying, the data for `resumeData` is already stored in a `bytearray` like so: `bytearray(b'\xef\xbb\xbf<html><body><h1><b>Ray Bao</b></h1><h2>')`

I want a for-loop that iterates over the cursor above and writes the `resumeData` column to local storage with the given `fileName`.

```
for row in cursor:
  #
  # Write to file...
  #
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* just write the data to a file opened in binary mode:

```
with open('filename', 'wb') as f:
   for row in cursor:
       f.write(row[2])
       f.write(b'\n')
```

However, note that your sample `resumeData` column includes a [*UTF-8 BOM*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8); you may want to remove that first:

```
import codecs

with open('filename', 'wb') as f:
   for row in cursor:
       resumeData = row[2]
       if resumeData.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
           resumeData = resumeData[3:]
       f.write(row[2])
```

to prevent polluting the file with repeated BOM characters (which really are not needed with UTF-8).

Your other option is to decode your data and write to a file in text mode:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
   for row in cursor:
       f.write(row[2].decode('utf-8-sig')
       f.write(b'\n')
```

where `utf-8-sig` is the codec that expects a UTF-8 BOM (but won't complain if it is missing).

If you want to write one file *per row*, open new file objects:

```
for row in cursor:
    with open(row[1], 'wb') as f:
        f.write(row[2])
```

again as binary so you don't have to worry about what codec the column uses.

Comment: OK thanks! How would I alter the above replacing the `with open('filename', 'wb') as f:` to pass in the `fileName` of the row within the cursor?

Comment: @RayBao: ah, you want to open a new file for each row? I'll adjust.

Comment: @RayBao: in that case it's even easier as you don't have to worry about newlines and BOM characters, really.